# How to change or swap the color for a stacked bar plot in R?

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart, swap, stacked-chart

I have a matrix like this:

```
my.matrix:

       A    B    C     D     E     F    G     H
[1,] 12.1 8.10 7.79 11.40 10.30 15.10 9.88 13.90
[2,]  0.0 5.45 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[3,]  0.0 0.00 5.42  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[4,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  6.55  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[5,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  4.68  0.00 0.00  0.00
[6,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  4.55 0.00  0.00
[7,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 4.32  0.00
[8,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  3.94
```

and I've generated a barplot:

```
barplot((my.matrix), beside=F, axis.lty=1, xpd=T,
        ylim= c(0,30),xlim=c(0,11), horiz=F,yaxt='n',
        axisnames=F, 
        col=c("black","darkolivegreen1","steelblue2","hotpink3","lightpink","gold","darkslategray1","peachpuff"))
```

and here is the plot:

[image]

So, what I want is to swap the colors of individual columns from the second column to the last one.

For example on the column 2 you can see green color on the top of black;
but I want to have black over green and the same for the rest of the columns while I keep the matrix in a same order.

Here is the example that I've colored with photoshop for the first three columns:

[image]

I tried to reverse or transpose the matrix but It doesn't work and I am kinda stuck in this part.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out with this problem!

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
barplot(my.matrix[nrow(my.matrix):1, ], beside=F, axis.lty=1, xpd=T,
        ylim= c(0,30),xlim=c(0,11), horiz=F,yaxt='n',
        axisnames=F, 
        col=c("peachpuff", "darkslategray1", "gold", "lightpink", "hotpink3", 
              "steelblue2", "darkolivegreen1", "black"))
```

[image]

Or, with regards to your edit:

```
m <- my.matrix
diag(m) <- my.matrix[1, ]
m[1, ] <- diag(my.matrix)
barplot(m[nrow(m):1, ], beside=F, axis.lty=1, xpd=T,
        ylim= c(0,30),xlim=c(0,11), horiz=F,yaxt='n',
        axisnames=F, 
        col=c("peachpuff", "darkslategray1", "gold", "lightpink", "hotpink3", 
              "steelblue2", "darkolivegreen1", "black"))
```

[image]

---

**Data:**

```
my.matrix <- read.table(header=T, text="      A    B    C     D     E     F    G     H
[1,] 12.1 8.10 7.79 11.40 10.30 15.10 9.88 13.90
[2,]  0.0 5.45 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[3,]  0.0 0.00 5.42  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[4,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  6.55  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00
[5,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  4.68  0.00 0.00  0.00
[6,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  4.55 0.00  0.00
[7,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 4.32  0.00
[8,]  0.0 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  3.94")
my.matrix <- as.matrix(my.matrix)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for; your result I've also got by reversing the matrix.
I've added a new picture to my question for the first three columns.

Thanks

Comment: So, effectively you want to switch the diagonal with the first row? See my edit